# PHP, MySQL - how to display all results from all rows with values higher than

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database with following columns and rows (few listed below):

```
ID |     Date   | Event
1  | 1994-05-01 | EventDesc1
2  | 1994-07-04 | EventDesc2
3  | 1996-02-02 | EventDesc3
4  | 1998-04-07 | EventDesc4
5  | 1999-01-01 | EventDesc5
```

I want to echo all rows from the column Event that happened after a specified date. The date would be specified in a php variable.

e.g.
Date specified: 27.2.1995; it would echo EventDesc3, EventDesc4, EventDesc5

Comment: What column type is that `Date` saved as?

Comment: What is data type of Date column?

Comment: Column type of Date is DATE. Sorry for incorrect styling in my post. So the dates format is 1994-5-1.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious: `SELECT id,date,event FROM my_table WHERE date > '1995-02-27'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understood your question, I think that this is what you are looking for..

```
<?php
$date = your date value 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Event FROM your_table_name WHERE Date >= $date");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; 

?>
```

Comment: This works great, but the variable doesnt seem to work. I tried doing the variable as both $date = new DateTime('1995-02-27') and $date = '1995-02-27' but none of these work. Do you know how to fix this please?

Comment: The variable value should be in "your value" i think check and say if this works

Comment: change that $row line to `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['Event']."<br>";
}`

Comment: Changing the $date to '$date' in the $result line made it work. Thank you